# Why does MySQL return 1175 code after calling UPDATE procedure WITH where clause which uses primary key?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I know that I can unchecked the 'safe update' mode but I want to understand why MySQL server returns this error even when all things look like correct?

I'm trying to call update procedure to update row in table `country` with statement

```
    call sellcontroller.country_update(1, 'United Kingdom', 'GB', 'GBR', 'GBR');
```

but it throws an exception "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column."
I'm definitely sure that I'm using a WHERE clause with table primary key and correct data type. And even more the same update statement used outside from procedure works correctly.

Code of the procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `country_update` (
  in idCountry int(6),
  in nameCountry varchar(255),
  in codeISO2 varchar(2),
  in codeISO3 varchar(3),
  in codeCitizen varchar(5))  
BEGIN
  UPDATE `sellcontroller`.`country`
  SET
    `nameCountry` = nameCountry,
    `codeISO2` = codeISO2,
    `codeISO3` = codeISO3,
    `codeCitizen` = codeCitizen
  WHERE `idCountry` = idCountry;
END
```

The table creation statement for now is

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
`idCountry` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nameCountry` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`codeISO2` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`codeISO3` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL',
`codeCitizen` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idCountry`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Look at this: `WHERE \`idCountry\` = idCountry` - What do you think should happen? Change your input parameter names to something different than the column names (eg. `in_idCountry`).

Comment: I have an input field with name 'idCountry'. So I compare the table field 'idCountry' value with input field 'idCountry'. Why shouldn't it work? Does MySQL deny to use input field with the same name as key?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks a lot. It definitely works now.